# The popUp(director). Corona SDK

Tags: coronasdk

I am creating a popup window in the main menu. In the popup screen do closePopUp (), and displayed the message 'could not change scene inside a popup'. Help solve the problem

Comment: Hi Bakunov, can you show some of your `closePopUp()` code so we can help you with it?

Answer (score 0):

closePopUp

```
function OnClickExitNo(event)
        print("click");
        if event.phase == "ended" then
            director:closePopUp();
        end
    end

    exitNo = ui.newButton{
    default = "src/img/exitNo.png",
    over = "src/img/exitNo.png",
    onEvent = OnClickExitNo
    }
```

and openPopUp

```
director:openPopUp("exit_screen", popClosed );
```

Answer (score -1):

try this ....
u should place the director.lua file in your project folder

**main.lua**

```
local director=require("director")
local mainGroup=display.newGroup()

function clean(event)
print("clean")
end

function main()
display.setStatusBar(display.HiddenStatusBar)
mainGroup:insert(director.directorView)
director:changeScene("screen1")
end

main()
```

---

**screen1.lua**

```
module(...,package.seeall)

function clean(event)
print("clean")
end

new =function()
local localGroup=display.newGroup()
local circle=display.newCircle(display.contentWidth/2,display.contentHeight/2,80)
circle:setFillColor(220,25,220)
local text=display.newText( "click to openPopUp", 0, 0, native.systemFontBold, 16 )
text.x=circle.x
text.y=circle.y
localGroup:insert(circle)

local listener=function(event)
if(event.phase=="ended")then
    director:openPopUp( "screen2","flip")
end
  end

circle:addEventListener("touch",listener)
return localGroup;
 end
```

[image]

---

**screen2.lua**

```
module(...,package.seeall)
function clean(event)
print("clean")
  end

new =function(prams)
local localGroup=display.newGroup()
local circle =display.newCircle(display.contentWidth/2,display.contentHeight/2,100)
circle:setFillColor(255,0,0)

local text=display.newText( "click to closePopUp", 0, 0, native.systemFontBold, 16)
text.x=circle.x
text.y=circle.y

     local listener=function(event)
if(event.phase=="ended")then
    circle:removeSelf()
    text:removeSelf()
    director:closePopUp()
end

    end

circle:addEventListener("touch",listener)
localGroup:insert(circle)
return localGroup;
    end
```

[image]